# How to find out the ethereum addresses of services like Digix, Augur, etc.?

Tags: blockchain, accounts, addresses

Is there any way to easily find the Ethereum addresses of Digix, Augur and similar Ethereum based enities? Or do I have to manually contact them?

Comment: You can find the major tokens at https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TokenTrader/wiki/Supported-ERC20-Tokens .

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean the addresses for the contracts?

Many simple services would advertise the address, because they only have one contract.

A more complex service will have a bigger network of contracts (for example Augur has around 30 different contracts deployed). Which address would be **the address**?

Additionally, many large service would have *proxy or lookup contracts* which have a fixed address and would return the current address of the real contract.

Answer (score 0):

You just transfer the Digix, Augur tokens from the exchange to your ehtereum address and then lookup the transaction ID on https://etherchain.org then you see which contract address was used

Answer (score 0):

@JaapH: Sorry, I don't know what is "contract address" and its use for what?
@niksmac: Could you instruct me: who is 'them' in '..contact them manually' in your instruction?

Answer (score -2):

I dont think there is a way to find it except you contact them manually, because

> Anonymity is by design